# Accessing My Domain Redirects to Default Gateway Instead of Nginx Page

Tags: nginx, router, firewall, modem

I'm encountering an issue while trying to serve a service on my computer using Nginx. Here's a breakdown of the steps I've taken:

1. I obtained a free domain from noip.com and linked it to my public IP.
2. I configured Nginx within my WSL2 environment to use this domain.

However, when I attempt to access my domain in the browser, instead of seeing the default Nginx page, my default gateway page is displayed.

Here's a snippet of my Nginx configuration for reference:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name zhaori.servehttp.com;

        location / {
                root /data/www;
        }
}
```

Additionally, I've checked my UFW settings and confirmed that port 80 is open. Here is the output of sudo ufw status:

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I've also made sure that the Windows firewall is not blocking port 80. You can view the screenshot of the Windows firewall settings [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvygb.png).

You also can view the screenhost of the router settings [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l40r.png).

In an effort to address the issue, I contacted my ISP and requested the opening of port 80 on my modem. The ISP responded by configuring my modem to set my router as part of the DMZ (Demilitarized Zone) but the problem persist.

As I'm still stuck with this issue, I'd really love any extra help or insights from the community.